# Ubuntu 12.10 Wireless on Macbook Pro late 2011 No Internet Access

Tags: wireless, 12.10, macbook

Is there a way I can download all the dependencies of b43-fwcutter_011-1_i386.deb and broadcom-wl-5.100.138 that I download from Mac OS X to use with Ubuntu. The late 2011 MBP doesn't have a ethernet port so I'm just trying to get the wireless to work in the Ubuntu part.

Comment: Your wireless card needs one or the other, not both. Please run lspci -nn and edit your question to add your wireless card details. We can proceed after we know which you require.

Answer (score 1):

Download the needed packages (`.deb` files) onto a Windows-formatted USB stick. Plug the USB stick in the Mac where it will hopefully get automounted. In a terminal, use `dpkg -i` to install the files from that volume.

Comment: where do you get the deb files?